# Constraint Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints

So I have a cell that is setup to have a collectionView inside of it. The height for that cell is given in this function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
         return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 300)
    }
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 280)

}
```

Inside the class for this cell I create a collectionView and again create a collection of cells inside of it.

```
@objc func setupViews(){
    backgroundColor = .red
    addSubview(categoryCollectionView)
    addSubview(sectionNameLabel)
    sectionNameLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 14, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
            categoryCollectionView.anchor(top: sectionNameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
            categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
            categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
            categoryCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    categoryCollectionView.register(CategoryEventCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)

}
```

Each cell has a background image and a title that is below the image. However the text is always somewhat cut off. My current constraints are here

```
@objc func setupViews(){
    backgroundColor = .clear
    setCellShadow()
    addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    addSubview(eventNameLabel)
    backgroundImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 9, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    eventNameLabel.anchor(top: backgroundImageView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

}
```

How would I change my constraints or text/element size to make sure everything fits?

My current view looks like so

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pinning the image to the bottom of its cell, and the label has no say in how to fit in. Instead you should pin the image's to the label's top, and the label's bottom to the cell's bottom. Like this in the visual format language: `[image]-[label]-|`. You also need to edit the backgroundImageView's content compression resistance.

Here is the fixed version where the label causes the image's height to shrink upwards to fit in:

```
@objc func setupViews(){
    backgroundColor = .clear
    setCellShadow()
    addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    addSubview(eventNameLabel)
    // ensure the image compresses, not the eventNameLabel, by lowering its priority
    backgroundImageView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(600), for: .vertical)
    backgroundImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: eventNameLabel.topAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    eventNameLabel.anchor(top: backgroundImageView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

Comment: wait so should I use the visual format or what you have written

Comment: The visual format is just to help you visualise what the layout should look like. You should use which ever you find easier. My fixed version should work so just use that.